# Combo Charts: Accessing configuration options specific only to particular a series type

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

In combo charts, the **series** configuration option in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart#Configuration_Options) provides only a limited number of configurable properties (**type**, **color**, **targetAxisIndex**, **pointSize**, etc.).

Instead of these properties, I wish to access configuration options specific to the series type in a combo chart. For example:

```
  ac.draw(data, {
    ...
    series: {5: {type: "steppedArea", connectSteps: false}}
    ...
  });
```

Wherein **connectSteps** is a property of Stepped Area charts only. How do I work around this limitation?

Answer (score 0):

The Google Charts Community has helped me out with this. The solution for this particular problem would be to set the `connectSteps` property at the `options` level, instead of the `series` level.

```
   ac.draw(data, {
     ...
     connectSteps: false,
     series: {5: {type: "steppedArea"}}   
   });
```